# How can I delete item from RecyclerView adapter's ArrayList, if I need to do it from another Fragment

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, oop

:)

I have screen with FrameLayout `flShow` to show inside it `DetailsFragment` and `ListFragment`.
I add to FrameLayour `flShow` `ListFragment` with RecyclerView of `val listOfItems: ArrayList<Item>`
When I click on any item from RecyclerView, I replace FrameLayour `flShow` with `DetailsFragment`.
When I click on button `btDelete` (which located in `fragment_details.xml`) I want to delete current opened  item from `listOfItems`.
How can I do it?

`fragment_Details.xml` has few TextViews with `Item.info` and Button `btDelete` to delete this item from `listOfItems`.

Comment: Share your sample code... What you did!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two fragments. in 1st fragment youu have a list & in 2nd fragment you want to delete an item from list.

You can do this scenario in two ways:

1- Add line below to app level of gradle

```
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.1"
```

Then after pushing delete button in second fragment you should pass ID of deleted item to first fragment by code below (I suppose that Id is 1)

```
setFragmentResult(
                    requestKey = "key",
                    result = bundleOf(
                        "id" to 1,
                    )
                )
```

now you should observe key in 1st fragment by code below

```
setFragmentResultListener(requestKey = "key") { _, bundle -> val id = bundle.getInt("id")}
```

after getting id in code above delete item from list

2- You can Share data between fragments by sharedViewModel
There is a full tutorial in the link below
[SharedViewModel Tutorial Link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)

Comment: Yo bro, it's good answer, but tbh I never tested it.